# Codeigniter routing not working while using my another custom routes

Tags: codeigniter

```
$route['404_override'] = 'my404';
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/templateOne/$1';
```

While using this `route` **404 error**, it is not working and 
showing an error like this:

This page isn’t working **example**. In redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
**`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`**

Comment: Hello! Can you show us your `'my404'` page? I think it redirects incorrectly. Also you may have forgotten to config your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: change ```$route['(:any)'] = 'home/templateOne/$1';``` to   ```$route['somthing/(:any)'] = 'home/templateOne/$1';```

Comment: sir ineed -  http://example.com/test   .      its working but that time 404 error page and some other pages not  working